# TypeError: object() takes no parameters while importing a class file

Tags: python, flask, python-import

i am trying to import a python class in another python file but i keep getting the error "TypeError: object() takes no parameters" but when written within the same file it works

i have tried the following

api.py

```python
 from flask import Flask
 from flask_restful import Resource, Api
 from flask_restful import reqparse
 from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

 app = Flask(__name__)
 api = Api(app)

 class CreateUser(Resource):
     def post(self):
         try:
             parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
             parser.add_argument('email', type=str, help='Email address to create user')
             parser.add_argument('password', type=str, help='Password to create user')
             args = parser.parse_args()

             _userEmail = args['email']
             _userPassword = args['password']

             return {'Email': args['email'], 'Password': args['password']}

         except Exception as e:
             return {'error': str(e)}
```

main.py

```python
from flask import Flask
import api as apii
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

CreateUser = apii.CreateUser(Resource)

app = apii.app
api = apii.api

api.add_resource(CreateUser, '/CreateUser')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

this is the error i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
CreateUser = apii.CreateUser(Resource)
 TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Comment: `CreateUser = apii.CreateUser()`?

Answer (score 1):

Your class, `CreateUser` takes no parameters.  You only need to put its parents in parenthesis when you first create the class.  When you want to create an instance of the class, you simply call the class, and in this case it takes no parameters.  The following should work for you.

```
CreateUser = apii.CreateUser()
```

if the `CreateUser` class had contained a `def __init__(self, name)` (for e.g.) method containing an initialisation parameter `name`- Then this would be reflected on instantiation of the class and would look something akin to the following:

```
x = CreateUser("JohnDoe")
```

Comment: i tried what you gave but it gives the error  "AttributeError: 'CreateUser' object has no attribute '__name__'"

Comment: that was an example, your fix is as above: `CreateUser = apii.CreateUser()`

Comment: @silent its not working i get the error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    api.add_resource(CreateUser, '/CreateUser')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 404, in add_resource
    self._register_view(self.app, resource, *urls, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 429, in _register_view
    endpoint = kwargs.pop('endpoint', None) or resource.__name__.lower()
AttributeError: 'CreateUser' object has no attribute '__name__'

Comment: it looks like at some point the library is trying to access an attribute within your `CreateUser` class that does not exist, `name`..  You need to make sure to implement all necessary attributes and methods in your `CreateUser` class in order for the api to use it successfully.   Unfortunately, I am unfamiliar with the library so I cannot tell you exactly what needs to be implemented